# Django queryset in multiple tables

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, inner-join

I have this kind of query using `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT 
tbl_project_lu.project_id, 
tbl_project_lu.house_id,
tbl_project_lu.project_name AS project, 
tbl_house_lu.house_name, 
tbl_project_lu.description,
tbl_house_mbr.person_id
FROM ((tbl_house_lu INNER JOIN tbl_house_mbr ON tbl_house_lu.house_id = tbl_house_mbr.house_id) 
  INNER JOIN tbl_project_lu ON tbl_house_lu.house_id = tbl_project_lu.house_id) 
  INNER JOIN tbl_proj_mbr ON (tbl_project_lu.project_id = tbl_proj_mbr.project_id) 
  AND (tbl_house_mbr.house_mbr_id = tbl_proj_mbr.house_mbr_id) 
WHERE person_id = 'foo';
```

Here's the model.py:

```
class tbl_house_lu(models.Model):
    house_name =    models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    house_id =      models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)


class tbl_house_mbr(models.Model):
    house_id =      models.ForeignKey(tbl_house_lu, db_column='house_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_id =     models.ForeignKey(tbl_person_lu, db_column='person_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  


class tbl_project_lu(models.Model):
    project_id=     models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    house_id=       models.ForeignKey(tbl_house_lu, db_column='house_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name=   models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description=    models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)


class tbl_proj_mbr(models.Model):
    project_id=     models.ForeignKey(tbl_project_lu, db_column='project_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    house_mbr_id=   models.ForeignKey(tbl_house_mbr, db_column='house_mbr_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is the best way to use this kind of query in django? Can Django ORM handle this kind of query or do I have to use stored proc for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using select_related() will pre-populate the appropriate attributes:

one Example  define with 3 model(City,Person,Book) and their dependency.

[see select_related doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Do you have an idea how to do this kind of query in Django ORM `FROM ((tbl_house_lu INNER JOIN tbl_house_mbr ON tbl_house_lu.house_id = tbl_house_mbr.house_id) 
  INNER JOIN tbl_project_lu ON tbl_house_lu.house_id = tbl_project_lu.house_id)` ? Thanks!